# Change each json object value with for loop

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to one by one, go through each json object and subtract 1 from each value, but I'm not sure where to start...resources on this specific thing are scarce online so I came here...

```json
{
  "12345678910":32,
  "10987654321":21  // after one loop will change to 31 and 20
}
```

```py
json_file=json.load(file)

for object in json_file:
    # subtract 1 from value
```

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with JSON. Once you have `json_file`, you have a Python dictionary. At that point, your question is how to change values in a Python dictionary, which will be a much more accurate search term to use.

Comment: I don't understand, I want to dump the new values back into the file once changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Inside the `for` loop you just need to

```
json_file[object] -= 1
```

and then:

```
json.dump(file, json_file)
```

Note though that you shouldn't use `object` as a variable name as it shadows the inbuilt class. Below I've changed your code to use `key` instead.

Full code:

```
with open('file.json', 'r') as file:
    json_file=json.load(file)

for key in json_file:
    # subtract 1 from value
    json_file[key] -= 1

with open('file.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(json_file, file)
```

Answer (score -1):

Some users commented that the previous function was too overcomplicated. Maybe with recursion the solution becomes more clear:

```py
import json
import typing

# A generic type. Why working only with `str`s as keys?
K = typing.TypeVar('K')
# Another generic type. Why working only with `int`s as values?
V = typing.TypeVar('V')

# A protocol type. Works with *anything* that is
# subtractable by another type.
class Subtractable(typing.Generic[V], typing.Protocol):
    def __sub__(self, value: V) -> 'Subtractable[V]':
        pass

# The first overload for the core function. You'll use this.
@typing.overload
def minus(
    iterator: typing.Iterator[tuple[K, Subtractable[V]]],
    value: V,
) -> dict[K, Subtractable[V]]:
    ...
    
# The second overload for the core function. We'll use that.
@typing.overload
def minus(
    iterator: typing.Iterator[tuple[K, Subtractable[V]]],
    value: V,
    accumulator: dict[K, Subtractable[V]] | None,
) -> dict[K, Subtractable[V]]:
    ...

# The core function.
def minus(
    iterator: typing.Iterator[tuple[K, Subtractable[V]]],
    value: V,
    accumulator: dict[K, Subtractable[V]] | None = None,
) -> dict[K, Subtractable[V]]:
    """
    Returns a dictionary where all the values from
    the input iterator [iterator] are subtracted by [value].
    
    >>> minus(iter({'a': 1, 'b': 2}.items()), 1)
    {'a': 0, 'b': 1}
    >>> minus(iter({True: 3, False: 5}.items()), 2)
    {True: 1, False: 3}
    """
    output = {} if accumulator is None else accumulator
    
    # Check if there is a new value for us to subtract
    # A try-catch structure is crucial for this task
    try:
        item = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        # If there is none, return what we have 
        # already subtracted
        return output
    
    # Otherwise, extract the current key and value
    key, current_value = item
    # Subtract it!
    output[key] = current_value - value
    # Call the function again. I love recursion!
    return minus(iterator, value, output)

# The main function. This is where your program runs!
def main():
    with open('your_input_json_file_path.json', encoding='utf-8') as in_f:
        # Type-cast your type to `dict[str, int]`
        data = typing.cast(dict[str, int], json.load(in_f))
    
    # Call the function that will subtract 1 for 
    # each value in the input dictionary (`data`)
    updated_data = minus(iter(data.items()), 1)
   
    # Write the updated data to another file!
    with open('your_output_json_file_path.json', 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as out_f:
        json.dump(out_f, updated_data, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
    
# You can use this to avoid external imports
# to automatically running your script
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

You can leverage Python [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module to accomplish this complex task. [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) too! Comments for explanation!

```py
import typing

# A generic type. Why working only with `str`s as keys?
T = typing.TypeVar('T')

# A protocol type. Why working only with `int`s as keys?
# Work with *anything* that is subtractable by ints:
class IntSubtractable(typing.Protocol):
    def __sub__(self, value: int) -> IntSubtractable:
        pass

def minus(x: dict[T, IntSubtractable], v: int) -> dict[T, IntSubtractable]:
    """
    Returns a new dictionary where all the values from
    the input dictionary [x] are subtracted by [v].
    
    >>> minus({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
    {'a': 0, 'b': 1}
    >>> minus({True: 3, False: 5})
    {True: 2, False: 4}
    """
    y: dict[T, IntSubtractable] = x
    for key, value in x.items():
        y[key] = value - v
    return y

# The main function. This is where your program runs!
def main():
    # The input data. `json.load` as an exercise
    # for the reader (you already know it!)
    data = {
      "12345678910": 32,
      "10987654321": 21,
    }
    # Call the function that will subtract 1 for 
    # each value in the input dictionary (`data`)
    updated_data = minus(data, 1)

    print(updated_data)
    # The output data. `json.dump` as an exercise
    # for the reader (do you know it?)
    
# You can use this to avoid external imports
# to automatically running your script
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I didn't realize this task would be so complex. Thank you for the help, I will look into it and let you know.

Comment: @Mashhhyyy Just to clear up the confusion, this answer is grossly overcomplicated for the task. The only important lines are basically `for key, value in x.items(): y[key] = value - v`. The rest is boilerplate unrelated to the question.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks for the input, I've rewritten the solution so it's more beginner-friendly. Can you check it out?